# svn comments added to file on commit?

Tags: svn

Is there a way to have commit comments added to changed files on 'svn commit'.  I have been told there is a way to do this with cvs, but we use svn.  Currently, we have it add the revision number to changed files with '$Revision' keyword.

Comment: You have 0 accepted answers of 9 posted question, and that is not nice. More people would help you if you accept answers to your question.

Comment: Oh.  Did not know that I had to accept answers, just always voted them up. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We migrated from PVCS to SVN and found that they do not have off-the-shelf support for these type of comments which we also think are valuable. All I found was the reason behind it on a FAQ from the SVN guys.

http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#log-in-source

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do this would be to use a pre or post commit hook. Looking at SvnBook it does not appear that the commit message is part of the available variables http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html

Answer (score 0):

I must be missing something here because comments are part of the [svn commit](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re06.html) command.

Here's a quick example: `$ svn commit -m "added howto section."`

Comment: yes...you are missing something, as am I.  I use the svn commit -m "foo" everyday, but a coworker of mine claims that with cvs on a commit, for all the changed files your commit can be placed at the top of the file.  So next person working on it will know possible changes.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer totally misses the point. The OP does know how to add a comment. The question is how to include it in a file. (Like the header of a source code, or a README.txt)

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**:

No, you can't do it Subversion

Explanation:

- Subversion has not internal keyword $Log$
- Changing content of transaction (during transaction, in pre-commit hook) is strictly prohibited (because it may give unpredictable results)

**At last**:

Log-message inside changed file is almost useless, because you can always use `svn log -r REV`, and get REV of last change for file with existing keyword. Just re-think about used post-CVS techiques